# Отключить авторедирект при наличии двойных слешей

Tags: http, golang, http-redirect

В чем задача, нужно отключить авторедирект у HTTP-сервиса на го. Авторедирект происходит когда вызвать веб сервис например так:

```
http://.....:8090/test/4833//test/.....
```

Т. е. вставлен двойной слеш, сервис сразу отвечает:

```html
<a href="/test/4833/test/.....">Moved Permanently</a>.
```

А мне этого не надо, мне нужно что бы отработал хендлер `/`, а в нем я уже обработаю данную ситуацию.

Создаю:

```golang
serverInner := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":" + ListenInnerPort,
        Handler: muxinner,
}

// .....
serverInner.ListenAndServe();
```

Вся проблема в том, что клиент который шлет такие запросы не поддерживает редиректы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам придётся сделать обёртку, убирающую двойные дроби:

```golang
func noslashes(h http.Handler) (wrapped http.Handler) {
    wrapped = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        r.URL.Path = strings.ReplaceAll(r.URL.Path, "//", "/")
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })

    return wrapped
}
```

В сервере соответсвенно вместо:

```golang
serverInner := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":" + ListenInnerPort,
        Handler: muxinner,
}
```

Делаем:

```golang
serverInner := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":" + ListenInnerPort,
        Handler: noslashes(muxinner),
}
```

А вообще клиента надо бить. Как за плохой *URL*, так и за
неспособность пойти по перенаправлению.

Comment: Не очень понимаю кто вызовет noslashes? В смысле его назначить хендлером? И сто будет  работать?

Comment: @АртемАртемыч Вы недавно в го? Это же обычный _middleware._ Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Да недавно, но про middleware знаю, но я почему-то думал, что это где-то в кишках сервера 301 ответ происходит, до вызова всех хендлов, попробую, спасибо

Comment: Супер, все норм